# SIR Parameter Estimation in Mathematica

Tags: differential-equations, distributions, parameters, systems-biology

- All infected individuals go through an incubation period, which lasts on average for 4 days. During this time, individuals are not infectious, nor do they have any excess mortality risk.
- All infected individuals eventually develop symptoms, and the mean duration of symptoms before either recovery or death is 5 days. Symptomatic individuals are infectious, as well as having a 3% case fatality rate. Those who survive the infection are thought to have long-term immunity.
- In the source country, the peak prevalence (i.e. maximum number of symptomatic people during the epidemic) was observed to be 8% of the population.

The total population of this country is N=11.000.000

\begin{align*}
\text{Case Fatality Rate (CFR)} &= 3\% = 0.03 \\
\text{Mean duration of symptoms (}D\text{)} &= 5 \text{ days}
\end{align*}

The rate of recovery ($\gamma$) can be calculated using the formula:

$$
\gamma = \frac{1 - \text{CFR}}{D}
$$

$$\gamma = \frac{0.97}{5} = 0.194 \text{ per day}$$

Then ($\mu$) is $$CFR = \frac{\mu}{\mu + \gamma}$$
So $$\mu=0.006$$
The estimated value of $(I_{peak})$ can be calculated as:
$$I_{\text{peak}} = \text{Peak Prevalence} \times N = 0.08 \times 11,000,000 = 880,000$$

The differential equations for this model is
\begin{align*}
 \frac{dS}{dt}&= -\beta \cdot S(t)\cdot \frac{I(t)}{N} - \mu \cdot S(t)\\
   \frac{dI}{dt} &= \beta \cdot S(t) \cdot \frac{I(t)}{N} - \gamma \cdot I(t) - \mu \cdot I(t)\\
  \frac{dR}{dt} &= \gamma \cdot I(t) - \mu \cdot R(t)
\end{align*}
What estimate do get for $\beta$ which corresponds to a peak prevalence (of symptomatic infection) of 0.08(i.e. 8%)

```
(*total size of population*)n = 11000000;
times = 100;
reportedData = n*0.08
sireqns = {s'[t] == -\[Beta]*s[t]*i[t]/n - \[Mu]*s[t], 
   i'[t] == \[Beta]*s[t]*i[t]/n - \[Gamma]*i[t] - \[Mu]*i[t], 
   r'[t] == \[Gamma]*i[t] - \[Mu]*r[t]};

initialConditions = {s[0] == n, i[0] == 1, r[0] == 0};

sol = ParametricNDSolve[{sireqns, initialConditions}, {s, i, r}, {t, 
   0, times}, {\[Beta], \[Gamma], \[Mu]}]



(*Extract the infected values from the solution*)
infectedValues = i /. sol;
```

I have tried the following code to Define a function to calculate the Poisson log-likelihood but it does not work.

```
loglik[\[Beta]_, \[Gamma]_, \[Mu]_, data_] := 
 Module[{output, modelI, \[Lambda], loglik}, 
  output = {i} /. sol[\[Beta], \[Gamma], \[Mu]];
  modelI = 
   Interpolation[Transpose[{Range[0, times], output[[1]]}], 
    InterpolationOrder -> 1];
  \[Lambda] = 0.6*modelI[data[[All, 1]]];
  loglik = 
   Total[Log[PoissonDistribution[\[Lambda]] /@ data[[All, 2]]]];
  loglik]

result = 
 NMaximize[{loglik[\[Beta], \[Gamma], \[Mu], reportedData], 
   0 <= \[Beta] <= 1, 0 <= \[Gamma] <= 1, 
   0 <= \[Mu] <= 1}, {\[Beta], \[Gamma], \[Mu]}]

estimatedParameters = {\[Beta], \[Gamma], \[Mu]} /. result[[2]]
```

[image]
I want to define a function that simulates the model for a given combination of parameters and calculates the Poisson log-likelihood for the epidemic curve of reported cases as R code shows us:

```
# DISTANCE FUNCTION

loglik_function <- function(parameters, dat) {   # takes as inputs the parameter values and dataset

  beta <- parameters[1]    # extract and save the first value in the "parameters" input argument as beta
  gamma <- parameters[2]   # extract and save the second value in the "parameters" input argument as gamma
    mu <- parameters[2]   # extract and save the second value in the "parameters" input argument as mu
 
  # Simulate the model with initial conditions and timesteps defined above, and parameter values from function call
  output <- as.data.frame(ode(y = initial_state_values, 
                              times = times, 
                              func = sir_model,
                              parms = c(beta = beta,       # ode() takes the values for beta and gamma extracted from
                                        gamma = gamma,
mu=mu)))   # the "parameters" input argument of the loglik_function()
```

So far I have figured out how to code it. My question is how do we generate this code in Mathematica, do I need Poisson Distribution? Could some one explain to me how could i code that?

```
  LL <- sum(dpois(x = dat$number_reported, lambda = 0.6 * output$I[output$time %in% dat$time], log = TRUE))
   
  return(LL) 
}


# OPTIMISATION

optim(par = c(1.7, 0.1),           # starting values for beta and gamma - you should get the same result no matter 
                                  # which values you choose here
     fn = loglik_function,        # the distance function to optimise
     dat = reported_data,         # the dataset to fit to ("dat" argument is passed to the function specified in fn)
     control = list(fnscale=-1))  # tells optim() to look for the maximum number instead of the minimum (the default)
```

Also, I know that the result of $\beta=0.38$

If someone needs it this the whole code I used in R

```
# Load required packages
library(deSolve)

# Define initial conditions
initial_state_values <- c(S = 11000000,  
                        I = 1,       
                        R = 0)

# Define time points
times <- seq(from = 0, to = 100, by = 0.1)

# Define SIR model function
sir_model <- function(time, state, parameters) {  
  with(as.list(c(state, parameters)), {
      N <- S + I + R
      lambda <- beta * I / N
      dS <- -lambda * S - mu * S              
      dI <- lambda * S - gamma * I - mu * I
      dR <- gamma * I - mu * R             
      return(list(c(dS, dI, dR))) 
  })
}

# Known values
gamma <- 0.194
mu <- 0.006
Ipeak <- 880000

# Define a range of possible beta values
possible_beta_values <- seq(0, 1, by = 0.01)

# Find beta that results in Ipeak
for (beta in possible_beta_values) {
  parameters <- c(beta = beta, gamma = gamma, mu = mu)
  output <- as.data.frame(ode(y = initial_state_values, 
                               times = times, 
                               func = sir_model,
                               parms = parameters))
  
  peak_time <- times[which.max(output$I)]
  
  if (output$I[peak_time / 0.1 + 1] >= Ipeak) {
      cat("Found beta:", beta, "\n")
      break
  }
}
```

Comment: "... but it does not work" - how does it fail exactly? Where is the failure?

Comment: Parameter `data` is not defined. Is it the same as in your previous question?

Comment: You need something like Total[Map[Log[PDF[PoissonDistribution[\Lambda], #]&, data[[All,2]] ].]. This is equivalent to using the density dpois. The PDF is missing in what you did.

Comment: @MarcoB I get the following message when I run the code, you will see it in my updated post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like we try to estimate parameter $\beta$ with known $\gamma, \mu$ using one point only `reportedData = n*0.08`. In this case we can compute $\beta$ as follows

```
n = 11000000;
times = 100;
reportedData = n*0.08; 
model[\[Beta]_?NumberQ] := (model[\[Beta]] = 
   First[i /. 
     NDSolve[{s'[t] == -\[Beta]*s[t]*i[t]/n - \[Mu]*s[t], 
        i'[t] == \[Beta]*s[t]*i[t]/n - \[Gamma]*i[t] - \[Mu]*i[t], 
        r'[t] == \[Gamma]*i[t] - \[Mu]*r[t], s[0] == n, i[0] == 1, 
        r[0] == 0} /. {\[Gamma] -> 0.194, \[Mu] -> 0.006}, 
      i, {t, times}]]); sol = 
 NMinimize[{(Max[model[b][#] & /@ Range[0, times]] - 
      reportedData)^2, {b > 0}}, {b}, MaxIterations -> 1000]

(*Out[]= {1.95698*10^-17, {b -> 0.510274}}*)
```

Visualization

```
Plot[model[b][t] /. sol[[2]], {t, 0, 100}]
```

[image: Figure 1]

We also can try to estimate $\beta, \gamma, \mu$ using one point only

```
model1[\[Beta]_?NumberQ, \[Gamma]_?NumberQ, \[Mu]_?
   NumberQ] := (model1[\[Beta], \[Gamma], \[Mu]] = 
   First[i /. 
     NDSolve[{s'[t] == -\[Beta]*s[t]*i[t]/n - \[Mu]*s[t], 
       i'[t] == \[Beta]*s[t]*i[t]/n - \[Gamma]*i[t] - \[Mu]*i[t], 
       r'[t] == \[Gamma]*i[t] - \[Mu]*r[t], s[0] == n, i[0] == 1, 
       r[0] == 0}, i, {t, times}]]); sol1 = 
 NMinimize[{(Max[
       model1[\[Beta], \[Gamma], \[Mu]][#] & /@ Range[0, times]] - 
      reportedData)^2, {0 <= \[Beta] <= 1, 0 <= \[Gamma] <= 1, 
    0 <= \[Mu] <= 1}}, {\[Beta], \[Gamma], \[Mu]}, 
  MaxIterations -> 1000]

(*Out[]= {4.87078*10^-11, {\[Beta] -> 0.88748, \[Gamma] -> 
   0.035164, \[Mu] -> 0.0405108}}*)
```

Visualization

```
Plot[
 model1[\[Beta], \[Gamma], \[Mu]][t] /. sol1[[2]], {t, 0, 100}]
```

[image: Figure 2]

What is the advance to use `LogLikelihood[]` or `loglik`?

Comment: The professor had said that the poisson log-likelihood gives better accuracy

Comment: Because the estimate value of $\beta$=0.38

Comment: Try `model` with $\beta=0.38$ at $\gamma= 0.194, \mu -> 0.006$,  You will get `Max[model[0.38][#] & /@ Range[0, times]]` of about  5178.92, or 0.047%. No, I don't believe your professor :)